# The Minotaur won't kill my dwarf, what can I do?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So let me preface that I am playing the (or close to the) latest version of DF under the stricture that my dwarves are pacifists. No killing, no violence except personal self defense. No militia. Cage traps are the only traps allowed.

[image] A minotaur has shown up, killed a Yak and Bunny and knocked one of my dwarves unconscious. Now it's beating him in the head with a cave spider silk sock, which isn't doing much. My dwarves keep running up to feed or recover the wounded dwarf.  This is putting a severe hindrance on productivity in the fortress.

What can I do? The only I have is to build a wall around the area. Is there a way I can make the minotaur my friend? Something else I can do without actually killing it?

Comment: I would try creating a militia consisting of that single dwarf, if he's unnamed and unarmoured, then he doesn't stand much of a chance...but this is dwarf fortress, so there is a chance he/she could break your pacifist rule.

Comment: I'm not sure what good that would do as he is unconscious.

Comment: "A minotaur has shown up, killed a Yak and Bunny and knocked one of my dwarves unconscious. Now it's beating him in the head with a cave spider silk sock,...". damn, I forgot how much fun DF was :D

Comment: With a sock... ouch! :)

Comment: Minothaur's socks can be terrible weapons...;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the burro<kbd>w</kbd>s menu and create a new burrow which covers the entire map (don't forget to include all z-levels). Switch to <kbd>r</kbd>emove mode, and remove an area around the minotaur and wounded dwarf. To confine your dwarves to that burrow, open the <kbd>m</kbd>ilitary menu and go to the <kbd>a</kbd>lerts tab.

The current civilian alert level should be `Inactive`. With that alert level selected go to the far right burrows column, select the burrow you just made, and press enter. This will prevent your dwarves from leaving that burrow, and since you removed the area of the burrow around the minotaur, the dwarves will no long enter that area.

Comment: Initial results suggest this is the solution. "Farmer cancels Recover WOunded: Patient inaccessible."

Comment: Glad I could help. I usually do this to prevent my dwarves from wandering in front of my ballistae :)